# WPF Rendered Polygon Shape

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I'm putting a collection of points into a Polygon shape like so:

```
<Polygon Points="{Binding vertices, Converter={StaticResource pointCollectionConverter}}" Stretch="None" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#7EBB9A" />
```

However, on relatively complex inputs, the polygon doesn't come out like I'd expect it to. For example, here is an output:

[image]

The problem is that this polygon has two interesections that should not be there. It should have these edges instead(in Red):

[image]

I'm not how to fix this, and if not I guess I have to resort to drawing it manually.

Comment: Can you tell us where you are getting the points from?

Comment: @nmaait Custom text file or mouseclicks on the screen.

Comment: In that case the solution would be to order the points appropriately, I don't think there would be a simple way to make the application check the ordering for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior and comes from the ordering in which the points are created. What is the source of your points and can they be reordered? If you were to swap the points indicated in the image below you will get the result you are after.

[image: Swap these two points.]